# Assign setInterval to a range form

Tags: javascript, forms, canvas, range, setinterval

I am having issues connecting my `setTimeout` (from the JavaScript file) to a ranger form (located in the HTML file).

The code in the HTML works on it's own, but not when it is linked to an external HTML file.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
//javascript
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var i = 0;
var speed = 50;

function smoke3() {
    particles = {};
    particleIndex = 0;
    particleNum = 20;

    function Particle(){
        this.x = canvas.width/2.7;
        this.y = canvas.height/5.6;
        this.vx = Math.random() * 5 - 3;
        this.vy = Math.random() * 8 - 6;
        this.gravity = -0.8;
        particleIndex++;
        particles[particleIndex] = this;
        this.id = particleIndex;
        this.life = 1;
        this.maxLife = Math.random() * 10 + 80;
        this.color = "rgba("+parseInt(Math.random()*50, 10) + " , " +
            +parseInt(Math.random()*30, 10) + " , " +
            +parseInt(Math.random()*50, 10) + " , " + "0.5";
    }

    Particle.prototype.draw = function (){
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;
        this.vy += this.gravity;
        this.life++;
        if (this.life >= this.maxLife) {
            delete particles[this.id];
        }
        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
    };

    function bigSmoke()
        var speedCont = document.getElementById('speedCont');
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < particleNum; i++){
            new Particle();

        for (var i in particles) {
            particles[i].draw();
        }
    }
    window.setTimeout(bigSmoke, speed); 
}
//window.addEventListener("load", smoke3, false);
window.onload = smoke3;
```

This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">Get a new Browser!</canvas>
    <script src="script.js" ></script>
    <script src="smoke.js" ></script>
    <br/>

    <form>
    <input type="range" min="10" max="250" value="125" />
    <div id="speedCont"></div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#canvas {
    background-color: aqua;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px ;
}
body {
    background-color: gray;
}

input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 500px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 3px solid black;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: I fixed all your syntax errors, and at least made something that looks a little like smoke work -> https://jsfiddle.net/fj463yq4/, you haven't explained what the range slider is supposed to do at all, and added no code for it, so that's anyones guess ?

Comment: hello thank you for your help!

the slider is supposed to make the smoke blow faster or slower out of the pipe, which is not in the .js file (it's in a different one that I haven't posted on here. So basically, I guess what I'm trying to say is that the slider would toggle the speed at which the smoke blows out in the setTimeout function and I don't know how connect it to the slider.

Comment: Wouldn't you just change the `speed` to do that -> https://jsfiddle.net/fj463yq4/3/